# Check if gradle subproject exists - from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I am integrating a large and complex gradle project (dozens of subprojects, tens of thousands of lines of gradle scripts) into a Jenkins pipeline. I am not in a position to change the build of the project and Jenkins pipeline simply invokes gradle using `sh` with the right parameters.

Now, from the Jenkins pipeline, I need to check whether a subproject exists in this system.  The subproject may be 4 or 5 levels deep, so the method has to be fairly flexible.

I can of course execute `gradle projects`, get the output and then parse it - but is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `gradle projects` from a scripted pipeline. Here's the relevant code:

```
def output = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "gradle projects")
def strings = output.split(/[\r\n]+/) as List
def projects = strings.findAll { it =~ / [pP]roject \'[\w\d:]+\'$/ }.collect { it.replaceAll(/^.* [pP]roject \'([\w\d:]+)\'$/,"\$1") }
```

It's not perfect, but it does give me what I need.